# This phrase "Including but not limited to" put me in confusion

Tags: grammar

Who has to bear the costs? Individual or Firm? Which are the costs does Firm will bear and which are the costs an individual/self has to bear?

All other costs, **including but not limited to** cost of travel, meals, taxes(including Luxury tax where applicable) and cost of various services and facilities at the participating centre, will have to be borne by the bearer of the voucher.

Comment: Impossible to answer without context.

Comment: Context!  First, what does the voucher cover?  It sounds as though the voucher covers very little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *bearer* of the voucher is the person who is holding the voucher; that is, the person who the voucher was given to.

If this is a voucher for a stay at a resort hotel, for example, the hotel will pay the costs of lodging, but that's all. You pay for everything else.

Comment: I just corrected. Yes its Voucher not firm.

Comment: I'll revise my answer then.

Comment: Does it mean Self or individual who is having the voucher has to bear all these -> the `cost of travel, meals, taxes(including Luxury tax where applicable) and cost of various services and facilities at the participating centre`

Comment: Please clarify.

Comment: That's what I said: the person who uses the voucher must pay the cost of travel, meals, taxes, and services.